# Getting MySQLi error on Moodle Setup on Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP7.4

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, moodle

I'm trying to install Moodle 3.9.7 on Ubuntu 18.04 and have been following the [official installation guide](https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Step-by-step_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu)

On Step 7 (Browser setup) I am getting the following error when setting up the database:

> Error: database driver problem detected
>
> The site administrator should verify server configuration
>
> PHP has not been properly configured with the MySQLi extension for it
> to communicate with MySQL. Please check your php.ini file or recompile
> PHP.

I've tried going to on `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` and uncommenting `;extension=mysqli` but it hasn't solved the issue for me.

Has anybody gotten this error or found an alternative solution to it?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after the `php.ini` change?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php-mysql; sudo phpenmod mysqli; sudo service apache2 restart` is typical steps for Ubuntu. Editing php.ini file shouldn't be needed, `phpenmod` enables the module for you. (Package name could also be `php7.4-mysql`, it's been a while since I've done this on a Debian distro.)